# Geolocation client side requests: Key and ID storage

Tags: javascript, keys, geolocation

I'm developing a small web-app to help users manage shopping lists.
 One of the required features is the ability of the application to notify the user if a shop of the same category is near him/her.
To do so I'm using Foursquare API.

- Said API needs a KEY and CLIENT_ID to make the request.
- Requests are made by the client via some javascript.

Should I have the KEY and CLIENT_ID in the client-side javascript or should the script use my web-app as a proxy for requests?

If the former is the better approach how can I safely save the KEY and CLIENT_ID in the client-side script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot safely store the secrets in clientside Javascript. Hence you need to go with option 2: proxy via the server.